# Why is my app failing to install to my device after upgrading to Lollipop?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-5.0-lollipop

After I upgraded the OS of my Samsung GALAXY tab to Lollypop I unable to build my app and received the following error:

```
Android: Unable to instantiate activity / ClassNotFoundException
```

What has happened?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting existing versions of the app from the tablet resolved the issue.